# swiftのキャストの言語仕様に関して

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

`as Int`と`Int()`の違いを教えていただきたいです。

swiftでキャストをする際は`as Hoge`とすると、キャストされるかと思います。
そして、`Int()`もIntにキャストしてくれる関数との認識です。
appleの公式ドキュメントを見たり、ぐぐってみましたが、両者の違いがいまいちよくわかっておりません。

以下のキャプチャのコードで、`as Int`と`Int()`でキャストをしてみると、`as Int`のほうだけ、
エラーが出てしまいます。UInt32をIntにキャストできないというエラーなら、`Int()`でも
同じエラーが出ていいと思うのですが、出ないということからすると両者の挙動に
違いがあるのだろうなと考えています。

そもそも、UInt32をIntにキャストできないのも謎で、
そちらも合わせてご説明いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。
[image: キャスト]

なお、補足ですが、`arc4random()`はUInt32の戻り値を持っています。

Answer (score 10):

asは「ダウンキャスト」を行います。
サンプル：（最初のimport Foundationは必要）

```
import Foundation

var myArray: [AnyObject] = ["Tomas", 24, 174.8]
let name = myArray[0] as String
let age = myArray[1] as Int
let height = myArray[2] as Float
```

型AnyObjectが、String、Int、Floatに対して継承関係があるから、asでダウンキャストできます。String、Int、Floatの間では、継承関係がないので、asでキャストできません。Int32もおなじ。

もうひとつ。typealiasで作成した型と、元の型の間のキャストも、asで行えます。

```
typealias MyInt = Int

let value: MyInt = 34
let value2 = value as Int
let value3: Int = 54
let value4 = value3 as MyInt
```

Answer (score 6):

swiftの`Type casting`はクラス階層上でのキャストです。
`Int`と`UInt32`には継承関係がないのでキャストできません。

> Type casting is a way to check the type of an instance, and/or to
>   treat that instance as if it is a different superclass or subclass
>   from somewhere else in its own class hierarchy.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

`Int()`はキャストではなく`Int`型のinitializerの呼び出しです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。継承関係がないとダウンキャストできないんですね。なんとなく、Uint32はIntにできそうくらいの認識で試していたのがまずかったです。
そして、Int()はinitializerですね。
どこかで学習していたはずなのに、完全に忘れ去ってしまってました。

Answer (score 1):

as Intは形変換処理で、Int(xxx)は**初期化処理**です。